# "Did not platform for taskname" error while restarting a job in spring dataflow

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using spring dataflow 2.6.1.
I launch a task, below entries are made in TASK_EXECUTION_PARAMS :

```
--spring.batch.job.names=abc
--spring.cloud.task.name=task-abc
--spring.cloud.data.flow.platformname=default
--spring.cloud.task.executionid=123
```

The task fails due to some reason(I put a code due to which batch fails).
But when I try to restart this job, it gives below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did not find platform for taskName=[task-abc] , taskId=[123]
    at org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.server.service.impl.DefaultTaskJobService.restartJobExecution(DefaultTaskJobService.java:195)
```

Platformname is already present in params table, I don't understand why it is not able to find it.

Please let me know what am I missing here.

Edit: This error is not coming in 2.7.0, it is able to restart the same task  execution(123). But the problem is 2.7.0 is not yet released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this was addressed via https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/pull/4170 and as you mentioned it is available in 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT. I think we should be able to back port this into 2.6.x so that you can have this fix available in the next 2.6.x release (possibly 2.6.4).

Comment: Thanks. Is there a tentative date for 2.6.4 or 2.7.0 release ?

Comment: 2.7.0 release is planned towards the end of the month (October 2020) or early November. We would have 2.6.4 along the same timeline.